# Как создать IT отдел

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

*Вопрос адресован прежде всего людям имеющим опыт организации IT отделов или компаний или даже кодерам проработавшим в серьезных IT компаниях.*

Есть некоторая фирма, основным профилем которой являлась работа с ценными бумагами (купить акции дешевле, продать дороже). Но теперь руководству пришла в голову замечательная идея - создать отдел IT который будет заниматься - написанием и поддержкой сайтов, разработкой мобильных приложений и десктопных программ под windows (собственные srm, приложения с ведением учета, корпоративный мессенджер и тд). В этой компании спустя 5-6 мес есть 2 веб разработчика, 1 c# и 1 java разработчик. При этом есть 3 руководителя (сам директор, который и выдает задания, 1 по общим вопросам и 1 из веб разработчиков ничего не понимающий не в c# не в java но назначенный руководить IT отделом.)

- Верна ли подобная организация отдела?
- Как организована работа в ваших компаниях и в тех где вам довелось работать?

Учитывая что руководство хочет выпускать мобильные приложения на все популярные платформы (ios, android, windows) уровень оплаты рядовым кодерам до 40к (фирма в Москве). На разработку собственной crm брошен 1 c# программист, второго пытаются нанять, но уже 3 мес никто не идет.

Подводя итог, прошу поделиться опытом организации подобных структур, ваше мнение стоит ли вообще тратить время на попытки выстроить работу или искать другое место? Сколько нужно человек на подобные задачи и сколько ставить им зп и кого назначать руководителем ? В конце цитата директора, наталкивающая на размышления - "Я ничего не понимаю ни в сайтах ни в мобильных ни в десктопных приложениях, но это никак не мешает мне руководить отделом".

Comment: Я не знаю дадут ли вам здесь качественный ответ, но советую разбить этот вопрос на несколько (так как здесь вижу несколько разных задач) специфических, перевести на англ. и задать эти вопросы на специализированных сайтах сети StackExchange: мне, к примеру, в голову приходят [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) и [Project management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/). Таким образом, у вашего вопроса будет намного больше вопросов и ответы от более квалифицированных специалистов (не уверен, что здесь много тех, кто разбирается в менеджменте, смотрит мету и захочет делиться опытом).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Благодарю за совет. На ум приходит разбить на 3 таких вопроса : Сколько человек нужно для ..{список текущих задач} ? Какой оклад установить каждому, что бы в компанию шли не только новички, набраться опыта и уйти в другое место? По какому принципу строить иерархию? думаю задать все 3.

Comment: Да, что-то вроде такого. И добавьте ссылки на новые вопросы на спец. сайтах сюда, будем за вас болеть:) Правда, я сразу скажу, что я вообще в этом не спец в менеджменте, и какие именно вопросы там онтопик, и как для тех сайтов составить хорошие вопросы, я не знаю. Но вы точно ничего не потеряете от того, что зададите вопросы.

Comment: Мне кажется, что "не новичков" меньше чем за 100 в месяц не найти, а 40 --  это вообще не о чем говорить.

Comment: @Сергей, 40к, это в долларах?)))

Comment: @Сергей, напишите ,пожалуйста, какова Ваша мотивация при написании вопроса и какие задачи Вы решаете для себя, Вас поставили в качестве руководителя? чтобы понять на что делать упор при ответе

Comment: @Сергей , помимо Java, C# и веб-разработчика в компании есть другие разработчики, которые выполняют другие задачи?

Comment: @МихаилРебров 1. нет не в долларах.)) 2. да. сейчас есть 3 разнонаправленных программиста  (web, net, java) формально web мастер 'руководит' остальными но по сути только собирает отчеты. Планируется набрать еще людей и тогда уже оставить 2 человек руководить - того кто на web заниматься руководством чисто web и меня на приложения хотя опыта работы руководителем нет. Да и не ясно есть ли смысл вообще с таким бюджетом.

Comment: @Сергей, в Москве даже в голодные годы веб-мастера больше получали. За такие деньги вы никогда никого не найдёте

Comment: @Сергей ,если коротко, то за 40к в месяц ничего толкового вы никогда в жизни не сделаете. Если нужен более развёрнутый ответ, то я его дам.

Comment: @МихаилРебров буду очень рад развернутому ответу. Тут хотят нанять много людей на 40к а потом повышать. Ведь 4х же нашли ) правда один уволился почти сразу да и я в размышлениях, с одной стороны руководителем обещают сделать, с другой - что то никто не спешит сюда идти.))

Comment: @Сергей , я напишу. но это займёт много времени с учётом моей занятости и ждать ответ стоит только вечером.

Comment: @МихаилРебров заранее благодарен!

Comment: *стоит ли вообще тратить время на попытки выстроить работу*. Если коротко - нет. Лучше бежать оттуда. Ничего хорошего не получится априори. Слишком много красных флагов.

Comment: Выглядит так, что ваша главная проблема сейчас - это директор. Он не понимает, чего хочет. Потому что "автоматизация своего бизнеса" и "автоматизация чужого" - это разные задачи. И перед тем, как бросаться решать любую из них, надо задать вопрос "а нельзя ли на этом сэкономить, используя готовое решение?"

Comment: **Три начальника на четырех разработчиков?!** И вы еще на что-то надеетесь?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov на самом деле 4 начальника на 3 разработчиков. Просто один не во что не вмешивается 0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Сдавайтесь и отступайте.

1. У вас большая ответственность и круг задач на душу коллектива. Кроме разработки есть ещё архитектура, документация, ревью (хотя бы самопроверка, но в идеале код должен понимать кто-то ещё), рефакторинг (начальство, не имеющее опыта в ИТ, часто эту часть недооценивает; работает и ладно), наладка инфраструктуры (если есть админ, хорошо, но ему надо сотрудничать с кем-то из разработки, этот кто-то должен в администрировании хоть немного понимать для эффективной работы), поддержание безопасности (нет, "шифровать base64" и использовать md5 это не поддерживать безопасность).

   Само по себе это не проблема, собрать коллектив которому это будет по зубам, возможно. Проблемой это становится, потому что... (см. следующие пункты).
2. У вас крайне самоуверенный начальник. Об успехе руководства можно косвенно судить по количеству выпущенных вами и используемых третьими лицами (хотя бы другими отделами) продуктов. Судя по вопросу, их пока ноль, а значит и об успешности руководства говорить рано.

   Обычно в такой ситуации отдел не приносит прибыли, потому не может себе позволить лишних расходов; лучше в такой ситуации фокусироваться на каком-то одном направлении, пока оно не взлетит. Вы же пока заглядываете дальше, чем имеет смысл.

   - Усиливает п. 1, не знающее специфики области начальство совершенно не обратит внимание на множество проблем с разработкой, пока не станет слишком поздно и проект не превратится в неподдерживаемый адъ, над которым никто не хочет работать и которым никто не хочет пользоваться (но обе стороны могут быть вынуждены из-за зависимости от дохода с клиентов и/или стоимости перехода).
3. 40 000 российских рублей в месяц при нынешней ситуации на рынке труда в областях Java и C# дадут вам в лучшем случае "толковых джуниоров". Более тёртые специалисты не купятся на возможность роста и просто сразу пойдут туда, где их оценят выше.

   - Усиливает п. 1, при вашем уровне специалистов вы много от них хотите. Посмотрите на то, сколько нынче дают фуллстековым разработчикам. Я не говорю, что вам нужны именно они, но нужны кругозор и умения похожих объёмов.

     Эти объёмы коррелируют с заработной платой. Несоответствия должны выявлять собеседования. У вас есть кому их проводить без помощи поисковика? А то может забавно сложиться, что организация интервьюирует кандидата, который о работе знает только ответы на вопросы из собеседований, в поисковике нашёл. А работодатель кроме этого сам ничего спросить не может. Хорошие рекрутеры, возможно, могли бы сгладить этот момент, но их надо ещё найти.

**Для меня такая ситуация выглядит безнадёжной.**

И я ни в коем случае не хочу оскорбить никого из вашего коллектива разработчиков громкими заявлениями о недостаточной компетентности. У кого-то из них компетентность может быть достаточной, просто недооценённой, а потому готовой исчезнуть в любой момент. Как именно? Смотрите.

Вышеизложенное исходит из того, что "система в устойчивом состоянии": что сотрудники знают себе цену и чувствуют себя на своих местах, они (хотя бы не не-) довольны работой и в общении с начальством нет систематических нерешаемых* проблем. Из ваших слов не совсем похоже, что это так.

Тем из них, кто по их собственному мнению не соответствует описаниям выше, стоит как-нибудь вечерком сесть и хорошенько порыться в вакансиях.

---

** нерешаемых в смысле, что их никто не решает, а не в том, что решение невозможно*

Comment: во многом  вы правы...и это печально

Comment: Примечателен комментарий относительно зп. На мое утверждение что на 40к толковые люди едва ли пойдут я услышал - то что человек просит высокой зп совсем не значит что реально много знает и поэтому наймем кого подешевле....

Comment: @Сергей уже оговорено в п. 3. Нужно хорошо поставить собеседования, возможно с привлечением помощи извне компании.

Comment: да именно. очень правильно все сказали по всем пунктам

Comment: @Сергей: Это правда, что если человек просит высокую зарплату, то он не обязательно хороший специалист. Однако если он хороший специалист, он точно попросит высокую зарплату!

Comment: @Сергей: То есть высокая зарплата — ещё не гарантия того, что специалист будет хороший. Но низкая зарплата — гарантия того, что специалист будет плохой.

Comment: Собственно, если бы специалисты всегда просили себе соответствующие их способностям суммы, собеседования были бы не особенно нужны в принципе. Достаточно было бы обмена резюме и вакансиями. То, что так не делают, намекает, что это не работает :)

Comment: @D-side Вынужден признать вашу правоту и начать поиски другого места. Особенно доставляет постоянное переписывание ТЗ (если его таковым можно назвать) добавление, переделывание уже сделанного.

Comment: За 40к в Москве вообще программеры не работают. Ни C#/Java, ни какие-либо еще. Там минималка на испытательный срок - 50к (причем это 2,5 года назад была)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну, сам этот вопрос тому опровержение. Только толку с этого... %)

Comment: @D-side судя по описанию - это какие-то студенты в гараже)